# Tag request: Prometheus

Tags: feature-request

I'm asking a [Grafana/Prometheus](https://superuser.com/questions/1680156/prometheus-blackbox-exporter-tcp-probe-returns-value-of-0-even-when-port-is-ope) question on SU, and I could see there is a [grafana](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/grafana) tag, but not a [prometheus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/prometheus) tag. And it appears I need 300 rep to suggest a tag (it should be noted I have over 3500 rep on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild)).

I just did a search for some stats:

[Search for Grafana](https://superuser.com/search?q=grafana): 44 results, has a tag [grafana](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/grafana), but this is only used 9 times.

[Search for InfluxDB](https://superuser.com/search?q=influxdb): 23 results, has a tag [influxdb](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/influxdb), but this is only used 8 times.

[Search for Prometheus](https://superuser.com/search?q=prometheus): 44 results, and does not have a tag.

*InfluxDB is another popular data source for Grafana.*

So based on these stats, I would sincerely suggest that a [prometheus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/prometheus) tag could be created. I would be willing to come up with tag description suggestions for both [prometheus](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/prometheus), [influxdb](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/influxdb), [grafana](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/grafana) and other related tags.

Comment: I've created the tag and added it to the question you asked today. When writing the tag descriptions please make sure it is not just copy pasted from elsewhere.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted twice, even though my suggestion was implemented. Someone having a bad day? ;-)